# Adding a whole folder (with subfolders) as embedded resource?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application that upon execution It copies `two folders with subfolders` that are in the same location to another windows location `%AppData%`

Now I have the following files :
MyApp.exe , Folder1, Folder2

In each folder there are subfolders. How to embed these two folders as resources inside the application so after compiling the program, I get only one executable file. And when I click on it, it extract the two folders to the same location then do the rest of job.

I know how to add a file as embedded resource then retrieve it using reflection,

but **how about a folder** Is that even possible??

Answer (score 9):

I had to solve this problem recently. I embedded a ZIP file, and then decompressed it at runtime.

.NET 4.5 [includes ZIP functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx). If not, use [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) or [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).