# c# add folders to resources?

Tags: c#, resources, directory

In my project, I want to add several folders containing different files to `Project-Properties-Resources`, but I found that I could't add folders to resources, which is the way I really need.

So, is there any possible way that I can add folders to `Project-Properties-Resources`? In visual studio, I only found Add Existing File, Add New String and so on.

Thanks in advance to anyone who read my question.

Comment: Why you "_could't add folders to resources_"?

Comment: @FirstStep I didn't find the option to add folders to resources, in Properties-Resources, I only found Add string, icon,image, text files and existing files, but couldn't find a way to add folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You compress the folders into ZIP files, add the file, then decompress at runtime.
            using System.IO.Compression....

```
        string startPath = @"c:\example\start";//folder to add
        string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);
        //add the ZIP file you just created to your resources

        //Then, on startup, extract the zip to a folder you control
        string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

To do this once per update, do something like create a setting for delete, set it to true on distribution, then:

```
 private void shouldExtract()
    {
        if (MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.DeleteExtractionFolder == true)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(myExtractionDirectory))
            {
                Directory.Delete(myExtractionDirectory);
                //unzip
                MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.DeleteExtractionFolder = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

[Adding a whole folder (with subfolders) as embedded resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452301/adding-a-whole-folder-with-subfolders-as-embedded-resource)

Comment: Thanks,will try and see.

Comment: Does this mean I have to extract zip files every time I want to use my program? Is there a way to do this only one time and then I don't need to extract?

Comment: Well, yes and no. You could, for example, put a check in the beginning of your program to see if the folder exists. If not, then extract. That would work but you'd need to make sure future updates deleted or overwrote the folder.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to put a "delete/overwrite" flag out in case you ever need to update (text file, database, setting, whatever). That's probably the easiest way to do it, presuming you even ever need to update the folder.

Comment: Ok, Good idea! Will try and see.

Comment: I can't believe I've never encountered/found the System.IO.Compression namespace.